# Re Size Excel Rows using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a working program that takes one Excel sheet and copies it to another.  The problem that I am having is that it  re sizes the row height.  Is there any way to manually set the row height for each row?  Here is the code I got:

```
    //Final WB setup
    tmpApp = new Excel.Application();
    tmpApp.Visible = false;
    tmpBook = (Excel._Workbook)(tmpApp.Workbooks.Add(templatePath));
    tmpSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)tmpBook.Sheets[1];

    //source setup
    srcApp = new Excel.Application();
    srcApp.Visible = false;
    srcBook = (Excel._Workbook)(srcApp.Workbooks.Add(sourcePath));
    srcSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)srcBook.Sheets[1];

    //Merge Both files here
    for (int i = 1; i < 33; i++)
    {
        string str = srcSheet.Cells[2, i].Value2;
        tmpSheet.Cells[3, i] = str;

    }
    //Re size row height here
```

I have tried `tmpSheet.Cells.RowHeight(12.75);`  at the end but it errors at run time.

Comment: And the error is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake.  At the end I set it instead to `tmpSheet.Cells.RowHeight = 12.75;` which works.